# Sort DB2 SQL results by WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to add a sort order to where clauses?

For example

```
SELECT *
FROM media
WHERE media_title LIKE 'query'
OR media_title LIKE 'query string'
OR media_title LIKE 'query string to search for'
```

I would like to search by relevancy of what the end-user input into a search box, with the last where clause being the most relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM media 
WHERE media_title LIKE 'query' 
    OR media_title LIKE 'query string' 
    OR media_title LIKE 'query string to search for' 
ORDER BY case 
    when media_title LIKE 'query' then 1
    when media_title LIKE 'query string' then 2
    when media_title LIKE 'query string to search for' then 3
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this version could be faster and even more readable:

```
SELECT * 
FROM media 
WHERE media_title IN ('query', 
                      'query string', 
                      'query string to search for')
ORDER BY case 
    when media_title = 'query'                      then 1
    when media_title = 'query string'               then 2
    when media_title = 'query string to search for' then 3
    end
```